# How can I SELECT a single result from a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to fetch data that is owned by each user. DB saves it with current user name and their data. Each user has many data rows. I need to get each users one row to be displayed every hour? so every one hour each users row1 changes to each users row2, when the rows finished it has to be loop again.

DB fields: id, name, message

```
$select=mysql_query("select * from commenttable where name='?'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
echo "<div id='sty'>";
echo "<img src='files/fav icon.png'"."' width='50px' height='50px' align='left' />";
echo "<div id='nameid'>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "<div id='msgid'>".$row['message']."</div>";
echo "</div><br />";
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question. If you want to ask a new one ask it, but don't ask new ones editing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '{'

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
echo "<div id='sty'>";
echo "<img src='files/fav icon.png'"."' width='50px' height='50px' align='left' />";
echo "<div id='nameid'>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "<div id='msgid'>".$row['message']."</div>";
echo "</div><br />";
}
```

Comment: I forgot that... {}.  Did you have any solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be PHP Cookie will help you in getting records as :-
Your table must have a column creationDate

```
<?php

if(!isset($_COOKIE['lastRecord']))
    $select=mysql_query("select * from commenttable where name='?' order by creationDate DESC limit 1");
else{
    $lastRecord=$_COOKIE['lastRecord'];
    $select=mysql_query("select * from commenttable where name='?' and creationDate < '{$lastRecord}'order by creationDate DESC  limit 1");
    unset($_COOKIE['lastRecord']);
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

 echo "<div id='sty'>";
 echo "<img src='files/fav icon.png'"."' width='50px' height='50px' align='left' />";
 echo "<div id='nameid'>".$row['name']."</div>";
 echo "<div id='msgid'>".$row['message']."</div>";
 echo "</div><br />";

 setcookie('lastRecord',$row['creationDate'],time() + (86400 * 30));

 }

?>
```

Comment: just send me your table structure